# Calendar with C — can't get it to work

Tags: c

The calendar only works properly if my second input is for Sunday. How do I make it so that it actually spaces to the correct day? And is there any way to make the code simpler, better, less confusing, and make the formatting of the calendar look nicer?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,number,startday;

    //getting user input
    printf("Enter Total Number of Day in the Month:",number);
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Enter Starting Day of The Month (0-6 Sunday-Saturday):",startday);
    scanf("%d", &startday);

    //formatting
    printf("   Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat \n");
    printf("_______________________________________ \n");

    //loop
    for(i=1;i<=number;i++)
      {
        printf("%5d", i);
        if(i == 7 || i == 14 || i == 21 || i == 28)
        {
          printf("\n");
          printf("\n");
        }
      }
    //formatting
    printf("\n_______________________________________");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `if(i%7==0)` instead of `if(i==7 || i==......)`

Comment: Please enable and deal with compiler warnings. You provide an argument for `printf` but no format specifier (twice).

Comment: [Homework night](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699598/example-code-for-c-calendar) but question has been deleted.

Comment: You should make an attempt to indent the first day of the month, and write a `newline` at the appropriate place.

Comment: @WeatherVane what do you mean by that, sorry my english is not very good

Comment: Obviously, unless you indent the first date, only Sunday will align. Your code makes no attempt to do that.

Comment: @George: UB can manifest itself before, during, or after the erroneous statement(s). It can even manifest itself during the compilation phase, before the program exists.

Comment: @George **7.21.6.1 The fprintf function p2** _If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
undefined. **If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are
evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored**._ So It's well defined.

Answer (score 3):

First read and learn true format of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) and
[`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).

You write:

```
printf("Enter Total Number of Day in the Month:",number);
```

It should be:

```
printf("Enter Total Number of Day in the Month: ");
```

and with little change on your source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, number, startday;

    //getting user input
    printf("Enter Total Number of Day in the Month: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Enter Starting Day of The Month (0-6 Sunday-Saturday): ");
    scanf("%d", &startday);

    //formatting
    printf("  Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");
    printf("______________________________________\n");

    ///fill calendar with proper space "  "
    i=0;
    while (i<startday){
        printf("%5c", ' ');
        i++;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=number;i++){
        printf("%5d", i);

        if((startday+i)%7==0){
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }

    //formatting
    printf("\n_______________________________________\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This code works, but I recommend that you check the user input 
to have proper format in integer data type and true range 
with simple `if (day < 28 || day > 31)` or `if (startday < 0 || startday > 6)`, and also check that each `scanf()` succeeds, probably exiting (with a message) if it does not.